# Where should I restore my android state

Tags: android

From Android Activity API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

It said "the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)". My question is where should I restored my state? why i can do that in either places?

Thank you.

Comment: Either is perfectly fine, whichever suits the flow of your program better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider restoring state in onCreate as the existence of a null bundle is a useful flag for other useful actions in onCreate.

Edit: Looking at my code, another reason to read in the bundle in onCreate is that I update widgets in onCreate. So the state needs to be known in onCreate. It does not matter if the state comes from the bundle or from prefs or from a calling intent. So the pattern looks like

getMyState(); // could be from a bundle or lastNonConfigurationInstance or prefs or a calling intent

someWidget.setYourStateFromInfoInGetState

Comment: But wouldn't that approach prevent the restoration when the activity is restarted? (i.e., when rotating the phone 90 degrees)?

Comment: @Aleadam A fun exercise is to write to Log.d in every state method. If you do this the following methods (not inclusive) are called onOrientationChange: onSaveInstanceState, onPause, onStop, onDestroy and onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

I will hypothesize here since I never used onSaveInstanceState, but from the docs, you should use the latter. onCreate is called when the activity is started, while onRestoreInstanceState is called after onStart(), that happens after either onCreate() or onRestart().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> protected void onCreate (Bundle
> savedInstanceState) Since: API Level 1
>
> Called when the activity is starting.
> This is where most initialization
> should go: calling setContentView(int)
> to inflate the activity's UI, using
> findViewById(int) to programmatically
> interact with widgets in the UI,
> calling managedQuery(android.net.Uri,
> String[], String, String[], String) to
> retrieve cursors for data being
> displayed, etc.
>
> protected void onRestoreInstanceState
> (Bundle savedInstanceState) Since: API
> Level 1
>
> This method is called after onStart()
> when the activity is being
> re-initialized from a previously saved
> state, given here in
> savedInstanceState. Most
> implementations will simply use
> onCreate(Bundle) to restore their
> state, but it is sometimes convenient
> to do it here after all of the
> initialization has been done or to
> allow subclasses to decide whether to
> use your default implementation. The
> default implementation of this method
> performs a restore of any view state
> that had previously been frozen by
> onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> protected void onStart () Since: API
> Level 1
>
> Called after onCreate(Bundle) — or
> after onRestart() when the activity
> had been stopped, but is now again
> being displayed to the user. It will
> be followed by onResume().